# To evaluate multivariable limit $\lim _{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y}{x^2-y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to evaluate this limit .

$$\lim _{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y}{x^2-y^2}$$

I think limit does not exists because when we approach from y=x, it blows up. which is not the case when we approach from y=2x. But i am not sure

Thanks

Comment: The limit does not exist. To see whay, use what you have done (the case $y=2x$, you have $f(x,2x)\to 0$)) and take now $y=x+x^2$. Then $f(x,x+x^2)\to 1/2$ as $x\to 0$..

Comment: Edit : The limit of $f(x,x+x^2)$ is $-1/2$, not $1/2$.

Comment: @Kelenner How did you come up to path y=x + x^2

Comment: As $y^2-x^2=(y-x)(y+x)$, you can  guess that putting $y-x=x^k$ for some $k$ will give you interesting things.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, limit exists IF AND ONLY IF if you can get limit from(along) ALL directions.

Once a counterexample founded(one is enough),the limit does not exist.

Since approach from $y=x$ gives a blow up, then limit does not exist .

Comment: Not quite. For this problem, the (natural, maximal) domain is 

$$D = \{ (x,y) \ | \ x^2 \neq y^2 \} \subset \mathbb R^2$$